# Was Euclid's 5th Postulate Ever Formally Proven?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, math-history

When reading about the history of Euclid's Elements, one finds a pretty length story about the Greeks and Arabs spending countless hours trying to prove Euclid's 5th Postulate.

But I've yet to come across a source stating that "this is the man who finally proved the 5th postulate!"

Has it ever been formally proven, or am I misunderstanding the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You misunderstood the issue. The creation of non-Euclidean Geometries (more specifically Hyperbolic Geometry) allowed us to see that the fifth postulate *cannot* be deduced from the other postulates.

Comment: Alright, appreciate it so much. Was really bugging me haha.